# IIS Rewrite Rule - 404 fallback result

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I'm relatively new to IIS Rewrite Rules so forgive me if this is not actually feasible in IIS Rewrite.

I'm trying to setup a 'fallback' route for some static content on a site. I always have the root content, but not necessarily the slug-path.  E.g.

```
http://example.com/some-slug/foo.js
```

If `/some-slug/foo.js` doesnt exist, I want to fall back to `/foo.js` on the root of the site, and serve this as the response.

Is this achievable in IIS re-write?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Yes it is achievable

```
<rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="rewritewithfallback">
                    <match url="some-slug/(.*)" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
```

Comment: This is perfect - Thanks!

Comment: However, this is not working in my case, I'm also trying the same thing. redirect URL `www.mydoamin.com/product/testproduct` to `www.mydoamin.com/testproduct` I have modified `some-slug` to `product`